# UIView tiled background image extends past bounds

Tags: ios, uiview

In the app I'm working on I have a UIView that I tile with an image of some green felt that I took for this purpose. Besides the tiling, which I do using

```
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImage];
```

I put a border around the bounds of the view:

```
myView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
myView.layer.borderWidth = solutionBackground.bounds.size.width / 120.0;
```

A drop shadow is also added to the view using a technique found here on SO:

```
view.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7;
view.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0;
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5.0f, 5.0f);
view.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:view.bounds].CGPath;
```

Here's the problem. Most of the time it looks fine. However, sometimes, the tiled felt extends beyond the border. The view is normally about 90% of the area of the full screen, so that makes the border about 8 points wide. It's my understanding that borders applied in this manner are 50% inside the bounds and 50% outside the bounds if there is no clipping. So how is it that the tiled pattern can extend beyond the border? Is this a bug? Or is the tiling limited to, say, a multiple of 8 pixels? Any other explanation for this bleeding?

Here is a sample. I think this happens mainly when the view is scaled using a pinch gesture. Could there maybe be a timing issue where the background and border are rendered at different scales while zooming?

[image]

Comment: Try `view.clipsToBounds = YES`.

Comment: How can I make the scope of the clipsToBounds apply only to the background? Also, I thought that property applied to subviews.